# Apply string.format() to row in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to represent a row in a pandas DataFrame with a formatted string referencing the columns.  The best method I have found is to cast the row to a dict and then string.format()

Assuming a `pd.DataFrame` `df` with the columns 'specimen' and 'date':

```
r = df.loc[0]
print("{specimen}_{date}".format(**r.to_dict()))
```

can be used to apply the format string using the column data.

This does not seem very efficient.  Is there must be a better way to do this in pandas directly without converting to a dict while maintaining the flexibility of explicitly naming columns in the format string?

Update:

The ultimate purpose is to generate tick labels for a matplotlib plot.  Using the answer below:

```
plot.set_yticklabels(["{specimen}_{date}".format(**r) for i,r in df.iterrows()])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use the row itself.  It is a `Series` which supports dict-like access to the items:

```
>>> d
   A     B      C
0  1  This    One
1  2    is    Two
2  3  crud  Three
>>> "{A} then {B} and also {C}".format(**d.iloc[0])
'1 then This and also One'
```